# Javascript when button is pressed a new form is added

Tags: javascript, html

I'am new to javascript so any help is welcome. Basically, I need the code to do is that when the button is pressed a new table is created.

```
<script>
    function table() {
        var td, tx;
        var fo = document.getElementById("fo");
        var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for(var x=0; x<1; x++ ) {
            td = document.createElement("td");
            tx = document.createTextNode("new table with form here");
            td.appendChild( tx );
            tr.appendChild( td );
           }
           tbl.appendChild( tr );
        }

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="New table" onClick="table();">
    <form name="Arvuti" id="fo">
    <table border=4 id="tbl">
        <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="text" name="Vastus" size="16" readonly="readonly"></br>
           <input type="button" name="uks"   value="  1  " onclick="Arvuti.Vastus">
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: `for(var x=0; x<1; x++ ) {` this will make the loop run just once.. then why do u need a loop?

Comment: You may start with putting your `input`s inside your `form` and properly closing all tags.

Comment: @punund The OP is probably trying to avoid the triggered submit event by placing just one input with the `type=button` outside the form

Answer (score 1):

try to use jQuery.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#new_field").click(function(){
            $(this).closest("table").append("<tr><td><input type='text' value='New field'></td></tr>");
        });
    });
</script>
<table>
    <tr><td><button id="new_field">Add field</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why do you think the OP needs a jQuery solution?

Comment: Also its much cleaner to use single quotes inside double quotes and avoid escaping

Comment: out of topic. no `jquery` tagged!

Comment: He wrote he's new to javascript. This is just one of options.

Comment: JQuery is a js lib, OP stated that any help is welcome since he's new. So this is a totally valid answer.